Algorithm to cluster face vectors by person for an unknown number of people
I am building an open source framework for image processing. One of my demo programs takes a directory of photos, extracts the faces, clusters the face embeddings, and generates an HTML gallery showing each person in the pile.
I have all of this code working. I'm using Scikit-learn's DBSCAN to cluster the face embeddings and I am not pleased with the results. The majority of the faces end up in cluster -1 (cannot be clustered) or cluster 0 (the blob). The other face clusters are great.
I've tried various epsilon ranges but the results are still not satisfactory.
I've tried SpectralClustering but it is incredibly slow. I basically loop with different values of n and see which gives the best results.
ChatGPT says I want to use Online K-Means clustering also called "Sequential K-Means" apparently (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698532/online-k-means-clustering).
I'm looking for other suggestions, and I don't have a good implementation for sequential k-means. Given that I typically have 10,000 faces, this might not scale well.

MiniBatchKmeans works with large datasets by iterating over minibatches rather than the entire dataset.
If you can first compress each image down to a smaller representation, Birch might work well for your large dataset. It was specifically designed for scalability.
sklearn has a large examples library including this comparison of the aforementioned algorithms.
There's the question of how to set the number of clusters. You probably don't want a cluster per image, so you could say that on average there may be a reasonable cluster for every 50 similar images. You could thus set n_clusters to n_training_samples // 50, and see how that does.

What do you mean by a "smaller representation"?

Also, I know that some pairs of faces cannot possibly be the same person (because they came from the same image). Is there an easy way to add very, very, very large pairwise distances between specific images?

I mean that you'd compress the image from its original size (say 128x128) down to a vector sized 20 or less. The latter is a more compact representation of the original data, which Birch handles more efficiently. About the pairwise distances...so you want to constrain the model such that certain samples don't get clustered together? Some sklearn.cluster accept a distance or connectivity matrix, however it is going to be $n_{samples} \times n_{samples}$ and the algorithms themselves mostly don't scale well.

Thanks. I'll give MiniBatchKmeans a try. It's not a big deal creating a n x n array for n<10,000.
